# Sharepoint multi level quick launch

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, quicklaunch, multi-level

How can I create a multi-level quick launch in sharepoint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want multi-level you need to write custom code.

For multi level quick launch the below link will help you

http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2007/04/26/customizing-the-quick-launch-menu-adding-fly-out-menus-to-sharepoint-navigation.aspx

Comment: Actually I was expecting some other answer other than the one in this website, because it is a little painfull. But thanks.